# matlab string number formatting

Tags: string, matlab

I want have a number

```
a = 0.0123
```

and I want to convert it to a string in XX.XX% format. How can I do this? The best I've got to is:

```
sprintf('%f%%',a*100)
```

this gets me

```
1.23000000%
```

How do I specify I want 2 numbers in the front of decimal and 2 in the back (i.e. 01.23% or if it was 0.123, then 12.30% )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
sprintf('%05.2f%%', a*100)
```

The [meaning](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is:

- `0`: left-pad with zeros if needed
- `5`: width `5` in total (integer part, decimal dot and decimal part)
- `.2`: two decimals

Comment: Thank you very much. Greatly appreciated